# android:scheme not work on my device

Tags: android, url-scheme

I have a custom link: callnumber://12345

I want to capture this link's clicking event by:

```
<activity android:name=".Test"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="callnumber"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have tested on many devices like: Samsung galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy 2, Motorola XT720
, it ran perfectly but on HTC Sensation Z710e, it didn't work.

I found that on HTC Sensation Z710e, that link turns into http://www.callnumber.com// and open it with browser.

I turned my intent-filter like this, and it worked:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.callnumber.com"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

But I dont want to capture http scheme, because it's easy to lost data when it changes from custom to http scheme.

Example: if my link is callnumber://12345# , it will become   http ://www.callnumber.com//12345 , it lost my character '#'

Or if my link is callnumber://12345#34567 , it will become http://www.callnumber.com//12345 , it lost my '#34567'

With above android devices list(Except HTC Sensation Z710e), it returns exactly data i want.

So how to capture custom scheme for all android devices, Or at least for HTC Sensation Z710e?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add data line as follows:

```
<data android:host="*" android:scheme="callnumber" />
```